# Show JavaScript widget only on index/main page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, blogs

I tried to integrate Twitter (via JavaScript widget) into a (static) blog page; now it shows up everywhere. Is it possible to show it only on the main page and hide it when a visitor reads a sub-page or blog entry?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  There are no further details we can provide.

Comment: sure open up index.html and stick it in there.. If that doesn't work im afraid you'll have to give us more info. ie. are you using a cms such as wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(window.location != '/<your main page address>') {
  //do sth to hide or do not show
}
```